# Как связать таблицы в базе?

Tags: sql, база-данных

Здравствуйте.

Мне нужно сделать базу, в которой будет описание сеансов в кинотеатре. Соответственно я выделил следующие таблицы. Но в этой схеме мне не нравиться то, что сеанс не зависит от зала совершенно никак, и нет возможности ограничить билеты на сеанс в пределах одного зала. Как это можно исправить?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Работал в кинотеатре. ))
Поэтому предложу такой вариант определения сущности сеанса - это период времени, в которое в определенном зале (их может быть несколько) идет определенный фильм.

Поэтому в сеансе нужно делать привязку к залу, на мой взгляд.

По поводу цены - тут она много от чего может зависеть - от самого фильма (очень хороший, очень длинный), от зала (Vip зал, обычный зал), от места в самом зале - (центр, боковины и т.д.)

Фильмы тоже лучше в отдельную таблицу выкинуть  с необходимыми атрибутами (продолжительность, жанр, название, и т.д. - тут кому что надо).

А вот это '...и нет возможности ограничить билеты на сеанс в пределах одного зала.' - не совсем понял, что под этим подразумевается?

Comment: А после того, как свяжутся зал и сеанс - ограничение билетов на сеанс будет делаться довольно простым представлением.  
В текущей модели пока на сеанс не продано ни одного билета мы не можем сказать в каком зале он будет. А продать билет, мы можем только в конкретный зал и на конкретный сеанс. Вообще не вижу, в какой момент может появиться билет :)

Comment: А то есть ограничение по билетам на сеанс подразумевается продано место или нет? - даже точнее можно ли продать данное место. )

Answer (score 0):

просто добавить id_сеанса в таблицу с залами
зал один (или несколько) сеансов больше... Плюс один айдишник погоду никак не изменит. А доставать данные будет легче при запросах.